# base point freeness of a divisor on surface

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $D$ be an effective divisor on a smooth projective surface. Suppose for some $E \in |D|$ either $D \otimes \mathcal O_E$ is trivial or has a global section vanishing at a finite subscheme of $D$. Does it necessarily follow that $D$ is base point free ( or atleast $kD$ is base point free for some positive $k$)?

I guess that if $D$ is base point free to start with, then it satisfies the condition (please correct me if this is wrong). My question is the converse, i.e. if $D$ satisfies such a condition, then can we say some multiple of $D$ is base point free?

Comment: I am not quite sure of your notation, but for example $D^2=0$ and $h^{0}(D)>1$ implies base point free. Because, if two sections are distinct then they are set-theoretically disjoint because if they touched then we would have $D^2>0$ by positivity of intersections.

Comment: @NickL,  Does that indicate one can possibly find  effective  divisors with $D^2>0$ satisfying the condition none of whose multiples are base point free?

Comment: I was not trying to indicate that. But it sounds true, at least I don't see any reason why not.

Comment: What do you mean by $D \otimes \mathcal{O}_E$?, It is a bit confusing since $D$ is a divisor and $\mathcal{O}_{E}$ is a line bundle on the surface. I.e. I am not sure whether you mean $\mathcal{O}_{D} \otimes \mathcal{O}_E$ or $ \mathcal{O}_E|_D$ . In any case I think the answer here is relavant https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4136446/nef-and-semiample-divisor.